# Set up DRF Browsable API Root with all api urls

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my urls.py I have many rest framework urls:

```py
path(
    "api/",
    include([
        path("users/", api_views.users, name="users"),
        path("proposals/", api_views.Proposals.as_view(), name="proposals"),
        path("requests/", api_views.Requests.as_view(), name="requests"),
        #...
    ])
)
```

I can visit the individual endpoints in the browser and access the browsable API, but I want to set up a browsable API Root where I can see all the available endpoints. The DRF tutorial has an [example](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/#creating-an-endpoint-for-the-root-of-our-api) in which they list the urls they want in the root, but I have a lot of urls and I want all of them to show up. Is there a way to include all the urls in my `"api/"` path?

Answer (score 1):

You can use drf_yasg package. But still if want show list of all apis you can follow the below code. I am using below example in my project.

```
def get_urls(request, url_patterns, namespace=""):
    urls = []
    for pattern in url_patterns:
        url_name = f"{namespace}:{pattern.name}"
        urls.append(request.build_absolute_uri(reverse(url_name)))
    return urls


class RootAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def get(self, request):
        app_names = ["accounts", "organizations"]
        endpoints = {}
        for app in app_names:
            resolver = get_resolver(app)
            endpoints[app] = {}
            for url in ["admin", "user", "public"]:
                resolver = get_resolver(f"{app}.urls.{url}")
                url_patterns = resolver.url_patterns
                print(url_patterns)
                endpoints[app][url] = get_urls(
                    request, url_patterns, f"{app}.apis:{url}"
                )
        return Response(endpoints)

urlpatterns += [
    path("root-api/", RootAPIView.as_view(), name="api-root"),
]
```

you can flow this repository for example. https://github.com/MahmudulHassan5809/drf-starter

this is the output of this API response
[image: outout]

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use `drf_yasg` package. Here's a [documentation](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/readme.html) for that.